# Android back button is taking me back to the same view but the class seems to have change

Tags: java, android, back-button

I have developed my first app and I am running into some problems now.
 
I tried finding a solution online but i didn't. So maybe someone can help me.

I have different activities in my app...the one that is called by the onClick in the settings menu, it opens up correctly, but if I press the back button, it still shows the same activity view (and only the menu of the previous activity). Active and working are the buttons of the menu but not the ones shown in the main view.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity { 
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
  /*  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }*/
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/WizardDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("WizardDB"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}
```

And the Activity that is opened by the menu

```
       package com.example.frank.myapplication;    
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.KeyEvent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.WindowManager;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ListAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;    
        import org.w3c.dom.Text;    
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

public class showgames extends Activity {
     private List<String> listSpiel_Id;
     DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        @Override

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.showgames);
            Intent EingabeName = getIntent();
           // Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            String[] favoriteTVShows={};
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            listSpiel_Id = new ArrayList<String>();
            db.open();
            Cursor c=db.getAllRecords();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    String Beendet="";
                    String Ort="";
                    if (c.getInt(9)==1) {Beendet=getString(R.string.beendet);} else     {Beendet=getString(R.string.offen);}

                    if (c.getString(10) != null && !c.getString(10).isEmpty()) {
                        Ort=c.getString(10)+" - ";
                    }
                    //android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd.MM.yyyy- hh:mm", c.getLong(2));
                    String Spiel=android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd.M.yy k:mm",c.getLong(2))+" - "+Ort+c.getString(3)+" "+c.getString(4)+" "+c.getString(5)+" "+c.getString(6)+" "+c.getString(7)+" "+c.getString(8)+Beendet;
                    list.add(Spiel);
                    listSpiel_Id.add(c.getString(0));

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else {

                TextView Zuruecksetzen1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Spieleanzeigen);
                Zuruecksetzen1.setText(getString(R.string.Spielwaehlenleer));
                Button ButtonLoeschen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonDatenloeschen);
                ButtonLoeschen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


            /*String[] favoriteTVShows = {"Pushing Daisies", "Better Off Ted",
                    "Twin Peaks", "Freaks and Geeks", "Orphan Black", "Walking Dead",
                    "Breaking Bad", "The 400", "Alphas", "Life on Mars","Pushing Daisies", "Better Off Ted",
                    "Twin Peaks", "Freaks and Geeks", "Orphan Black", "Walking Dead",
                    "Breaking Bad", "The 400", "Alphas", "Life on Mars"};*/

            // The ListAdapter acts as a bridge between the data and each ListItem
            // You fill the ListView with a ListAdapter. You pass it a context represented by
            // this. A Context provides access to resources you need.
            // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is one of the resources needed.
            // It is a predefined layout provided by Android that stands in as a default

            ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    list);

            // ListViews display data in a scrollable list
            ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);

            // Tells the ListView what data to use
            theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

            theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String tvShowPicked = "You selected " +
                            String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

                  //  Toast.makeText(showgames.this, listSpiel_Id.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(showgames.this, table.class);
                    getNameScreenIntent.putExtra("Spiel_ID", Long.valueOf(listSpiel_Id.get(i)));
                    db.open();
                    int Spielerzahl=db.getZahlderSpieler(Long.valueOf(listSpiel_Id.get(i)));
                    db.close();
                    ((MyApplication) showgames.this.getApplication()).setSpielerzahl(Spielerzahl);
                    startActivity(getNameScreenIntent);
                }
            });
        //    Toast.makeText(this, "Spiele anzeigen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    public void OnClickDatenLoeschen(View view) {
    db.Tabellenleeren();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alle bisherigen Spiele gelöscht", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

        startActivity(getNameScreenIntent);
    }
    }
```

Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  package="com.example.frank.myapplication">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name="com.example.frank.myapplication.AndroidDatabaseManager" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.frank.myapplication.getcurrentlocation" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".table"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.frank.myapplication.showgames"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
</application>
```

Could it be that it still thinks that the menubutton was pressed?

```
    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "huhu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return true;     
         }
         if (id == R.id.action_showlist) {
             setContentView(R.layout.showgames);
             Intent a = new Intent(this, showgames.class);
             a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             startActivity(a);
             //Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(this, showgames.class);
             //startActivity(getNameScreenIntent);
             //Toast.makeText(this, "Spiele anzeigen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return true;

         }

         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Would be lovely if someone could tell me why the first activity doesnt show up anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your talking about pressing back button , but i didn't see any implementation of method

```
 onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

so override this method and also:

remove this :

```
 if (id == R.id.action_showlist) {
 -->>> setContentView(R.layout.showgames);
```

Activity "showgames" will set layout on onCreate method.

Comment: Thank you. Removing thesetContenview did already do the trick.
The back button works now as I expect it. Is it neccessary/recommended to use the onKeyDown?

Comment: onKeyDown ... yes ...recommended if your wanna inform user that he will quit current activity...
Happy that my post resolve the problem :)